# How to select textbox value and move to the another textbox using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to enter the value in one textbox and then select all values and after I want to move that value in another textbox.

[image]

In the above image, I want to move the selected value into the Card Number textbox. Because card number textbox is not allowed to type using the keyboard. it only allows to Past the value. I have already asked a question but unfortunately did not get any help.

[This is my asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70616854/how-to-copy-data-from-excel-file-and-paste-into-card-number-textbox-in-selenium)

Comment: You can paste the copied value using [PyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html). Install it using [`pip install pyautogui`](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/) and use `pyautogui.write(copied_value)` to paste it. (First, select the card number textbox using selenium)

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder Can you please describe how to copy value and how to write using `PyAutoGUI`?

Comment: I tried pasting that value but I could not even copy paste any number into that card number text_field.

Comment: @KrupalVaghasiya as Rajagopalan said even i am not able to write or paste anything in card number. i think you are using react so my i guess is you have not write handling the input tag in front end correctly please check that .

Comment: I posted an answer on the previous question for you.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan it works but it seems like we are violating something when we do through Javascript `setAttribute`

Comment: @KrupalVaghasiya very sorry; I didn't test it then. PyAutoGUI won't help. I tried @Arundeep Chohan's answer; it didn't work for me either. But one of my methods worked; after trying the methods one by one, I finally found that `input.removeAttribute("value");` (using `driver.execute_script()` and getting the input with its XPath) works, but the value is changed back in a flash, probably due to the element's properties. I finally tried and found another method that changes it. It's just a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `input`'s `oninput` method makes it reset its `value`. Changing/overriding it did it for me:

```py
driver.execute_script('''function getElementByXpath(path) {
  return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}
cnoinput = getElementByXpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/input");
cnoinput.oninput = function(){this.value = "0000 0000 0000 0000"};
cnoinput.removeAttribute('value');
''')
```

`cnoinput` is the input element.
Changing what would happen when something's typed into it, by changing its `oninput` function, that changes the input's value to "0000 0000 0000 0000" will prevent the default behaviour of the element and will *only* keep changing its value to "0000 0000 0000 0000".

Replace that function with what you'd like to do (paste the copied value from Excel).
I got the `getElementByXpath(path)` function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14284815/16136190).

This is the full code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import pyautogui
#Imports

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://ibis-dev.droicelabs.us/login/practice")


email = ''
while not email:
    try:
        email = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'email') #Get the Email input
    except:
        continue

#Wait till the input is loaded, but I think this method will be faster than WebDriverWait. 
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/53023604/16136190

email.click()

pyautogui.write("krupal.practice@getnada.com") #"write" or type the Email

pwd = ''
while not pwd:
    try:
        pwd = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'password')
    except:
        continue

pwd.click()
pyautogui.write("Test@2020")

login = ''
while not login:
    try:
        login = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@value='SIGN IN']")
    except:
        continue

login.click()

time.sleep(2) #Assuming the time to log in is less than 2 seconds. If not, increase it.
driver.get("https://ibis-dev.droicelabs.us/practice/orders/61d7c50335afc005e70aac00/payment/?section=health_insurance")
#Because the login details are already stored, just load the page.

cardno = ''
while not cardno:
    try:
        cardno = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/input")
    except:
        continue

cardno.click()

driver.execute_script('''function getElementByXpath(path) {
  return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}
cnoinput = getElementByXpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/input");
cnoinput.oninput = function(){this.value = "0000 0000 0000 0000"}; // Change this function.
cnoinput.removeAttribute('value'); //Trigger oninput.
''')
```

Comment: When I execute your code test will pass but it does not enter the value in the card number filled.

Comment: @KrupalVaghasiya, what do you mean? Very sorry if I've misunderstood anything. [It changes the value](https://ufile.io/hgwo48hv)...

Comment: It will not enter value in the textbox but still test is passed.

Comment: @KrupalVaghasiya, what exactly do you mean by "test is passed"? Sorry, I'm new to software testing. The code changes the `input`'s `value` attribute. You can check using DevTools' inspect element. It has the value attribute and doesn't get reset even on user input.

Comment: Can you please help me on this question? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70651274/returning-wrong-data-from-excel-when-i-am-trying-to-read-data-from-an-excel-file]