# Returning wrong data from Excel while reading data using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, selenium, openpyxl, data-driven-tests

I have created an excel file for managing data for my test. When the script is run, it will create a patient, and write the patient name and last name into an excel file.

Then I have used that patient for my order creation. At this point, the script is working fine.
But after order creation, I want to search patients, and for that, when I read data from an excel file, it should send the data used when the script was run last time.

Please check this video for more clarification [here](https://www.loom.com/share/5fccbe2601404dcf8c9461bfee8ccc6e)

It will create an order using a new patient, but when I search for a patient, it should catch old data from an excel file.

When I run a single test, it will work. But when I run all tests together, it will return old data. Please check video [here](https://www.loom.com/share/254f415d9a6246169eec2e3dd2edff10)

```py
FilePath = "C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProject/LegrandePython/TestData/Data.xlsx"
datafile = load_workbook(FilePath, data_only=True)
testData = datafile['Test Data']
```

This works fine when I create an order for the created patient.

```py
PatientSearch.send_keys(testData.cell(2, 1).value)
```

But when I try to search for patients, it should send the old data from the excel sheet.

```py
self.driver = setup
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(DispenserLocators.patientSearch).send_keys(testData.cell(2, 1).value)
```

Comment: Please include relevant code in your question.

Comment: It's not possible to see what's wrong from that code.

Comment: @CharlieClark I have updated my question please check if you got any idea.